# Как в phpmyadmin массово заменить NULL на нужный мне текст?

Tags: phpmyadmin

В инструменте "поиск и замена" в поле "что заменить" ввожу "NULL", но система таких строк не находит. Как заменить такие строки нужным мне значением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpMyAdmin ищет *строку* 'NULL' которая **не равна** *значению* 'NULL', поэтому придется воспользоваться SQL-запросом

```sql
update table_name
    set column_name = 'value'
    where column_name is null;
```

Comment: А через "поиск и замена" нельзя никак? Просто в pphpmyadmin у меня почему то верстка поехала, не могу консолью воспользоваться

Comment: @Новичёк возможно я плохо смотрел, но не нашел как это сделать по другому.

Comment: @Новичёк можно, но в выпадающем списке выбирайте не =, а 'IS NULL'.